# How do I detect paragraphs when writing and reading xml and display them correctly on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, repeater, paragraphs

What I was trying to figure out (*unfortunately unsuccessful*) was how I could detect whether the user has made a **new paragraph** while writing in a asp:textBox and then save this information in the xml to display it correctly on the page (by for instance replacing with `<br />` s) when reading the xml and rendering it on the page via repeater.

This is my `textBox`:

```
<div><asp:TextBox ID="EdtMessage" Columns="56" Rows="7" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" /></div>
```

This is how I **write the xml**:

```
var file = Server.MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml");

var message = new XElement("contact",
    new XElement("name", s_name.Trim()),
    new XElement("message", s_message.Trim()),
    new XElement("date", System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()),
    new XElement("dateOrder", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
var doc = new XDocument();

if (ckeckFileExistance(file))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    doc.Element("messages").Add(message);
}
else
{
    doc = new XDocument(new XElement("messages", message));
}
doc.Save(file);
```

and this is how I read the xml:

```
DataSet messages = new DataSet();
try
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml"));
    /*messages.ReadXml(MapPath("~/_xml/messages.xml"));*/
    myMessages.DataSource = doc.Elements("messages").Elements("contact").OrderByDescending(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Element("dateOrder").Value));
    myMessages.DataBind();
}
```

**[edit]**
This is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myMessages" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="message">
            <div class="messageHeader">
                <span><p><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(((XElement)Container.DataItem).Element("name"), "Value")%></b> wrote:</p></span><div class="date"><p><%# DataBinder.Eval(((XElement)Container.DataItem).Element("date"), "Value")%></p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="splitLine"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="messageText">
                <span><p><%# DataBinder.Eval(((XElement)Container.DataItem).Element("message"), "Value")%></p></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace instances of [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) with `<br/>`:

```
myMessages.DataSource = 
      doc.Elements("messages").Elements("contact")
      .OrderByDescending(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Element("dateOrder").Value))
      .Select(message => message.Value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"));
```

*Update*

Based on your repeater markup, I would disregard my above suggestion and change your messageText markup instead. Something like this should work:

```
<div class="messageText">
    <span><p>
       <%# ((XElement)Container.DataItem).Element("message").Value
                .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>") %>
    </p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't excaclty know why, but It does not quite work. Now it displays nothing but one entry with no data in it. :(

Comment: You may have to change your repeater markup since the DataSource in my example is `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Comment: I edited my question and added my repeater. I'm not sure how excactly I have to change it..?

Comment: Is it not impossible for this to work as there probably is no information about paragraphs saved in the xml and they're just being replaced with spaces? Because it's still displaying them as spaces.

Comment: It's possible that the new lines are being removed before the xml is saved. Have you tried stepping through your code to see if/when line breaks are removed?

Comment: I have no idea, look at the code in my question about how I write the xml...that's actually all it does...and the trim() function has  nothing to do with it.